# Displaying data from a database using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phpmyadmin

Basically what I am trying to do is ng-repeat records from my database, however, I am getting the following error 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token F in JSON at position 0'.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in data">
    <td>{{x.songName}}</td>
    <td>{{x.albumName}}</td>
</tr>
```

JS

```
$scope.loadTracks = function(){
    $http.get('includes/functions/gettrack.php').success(function(data){
        $scope.data = data;
    })
}
```

PHP

```
<?php

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json");

    $data = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tracks";

    // Create a prepared statement
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);

    // Prepare the prepared statement
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        // Error exists
        die('Fatal error: service unavailable at this time');
    } else {

        // Run parameters inside the database
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);


        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            // Check for results and assign results to array
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You haven't shown any js...

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: something is wrong with your JSON. We can't help you if you don't post it here

Comment: please add more code and json

Comment: Yep sorry, hit enter whilst editing, I've updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your code is executing `die('Fatal error: service unavailable at this time');`. Character 0 of that string is `F` which matches your error.

The JS will be trying to decode `Fatal error: service unavailable at this time` which is not valid JSON.

[die()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) does not set an http code so the AJAX request will be considered successful. Try setting the code with [http_response_code()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php):

```
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    // Error exists
    http_response_code(500);
    die('Fatal error: service unavailable at this time');
} else {
```

You should also adjust your AJAX call to deal with the error:

```
$http.get('includes/functions/gettrack.php').success(function(data){
    $scope.data = data;
}).fail(function(){
    console.error('AJAX call failed');
});
```

Alternatively you could change the string being returned within [die()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php), but I would advise that this is not really a good way to fix it.

```
die('"Fatal error: service unavailable at this time"');
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped I've added your code in! I was so stupid in forgetting "require_once '../../config/db_connect.php';".

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the connection to the database...

```
$connect = mysqli_connect($db['hostname'],$db['username'],$db['password'],$db['database']);
```